# Como categorizar un dataframe con python

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

estoy usando python y pandas para ordenar un dataframe que he catogorizado usando una columna con datos booleanos como la siguiente:

```
df:

X    Y    PROB
2    4    False
3    5    False
3    2    False
4    4    True
3    7    True
2    4    False
2    3    False
```

quiero obtener 2 nuevos dataframes que presenten los datos 'X' y 'Y' con Falsos consecutivos o Verdaderos consecutivos como sigue para Falsos:

```
X   Y  PROB
2   4   1
3   5   1
3   2   1
2   4   2  
2   3   2
```

en el caso de los verdaderos:

```
X   Y  PROB
4   4   1
3   7   1
```

Hasta el momento estoy usando `factorize` pero no logro la sintaxis correcta para presentar los datos, alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

Primero vamos a crear un ejemplo reproducible basado en el que proporcionas:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'X': [2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2], 
        'Y': [4, 5, 2, 4, 7, 4, 3], 
        'PROB': [False, False, False, True, True, False, False]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['X', 'Y', 'PROB'])
```

Para solventar estos casos, una forma muy simple es usar [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) para comparar cada elemento con el anterior y ver si son iguales. Si se usa junto a [`pandas.DataFrame.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) obtenemos las categorías numeradas. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> df['Categorias'] = (df.PROB != df.PROB.shift()).cumsum()
>>> df

   X  Y   PROB  Categorias
0  2  4  False           1
1  3  5  False           1
2  3  2  False           1
3  4  4   True           2
4  3  7   True           2
5  2  4  False           3
6  2  3  False           3
```

En tu caso, quieres que la numeración de las categorías sean independientes para cada sub-dataframe obtenido al separar según la columna `PROB`. Para ello podemos volver a aplicar la misma operación sobre cada DataFrame obtenido. Para obtener los "verdaderos" y "falsos" basta con usar la columna `PROB` como mascara booleana:

```
aux = (df.PROB != df.PROB.shift()).cumsum()    

falsos = df[~df.PROB].copy()
falsos['PROB']=(aux[~df.PROB]!=aux[~df.PROB].shift()).cumsum()

verdaderos = df[df.PROB].copy()
verdaderos['PROB']=(aux[df.PROB]!=aux[df.PROB].shift()).cumsum()

del(aux)
```

**Salida:**

```
>>> df

   X  Y   PROB
0  2  4  False
1  3  5  False
2  3  2  False
3  4  4   True
4  3  7   True
5  2  4  False
6  2  3  False

>>> verdaderos

   X  Y  PROB
3  4  4     1
4  3  7     1

>>> falsos

   X  Y  PROB
0  2  4     1
1  3  5     1
2  3  2     1
5  2  4     2
6  2  3     2
```

Comment: Funciona muy bien, estaba intentando algo parecido, pero me quedaba en el `df` con la columna de categorias, de alli intentaba usar `groupby('PROB')` para despues cortar el dataframe, pero creo que no es posible conusar 'groupby' con booleanos? Muchas gracias!

Comment: @JonathanPacheco no se que estabas intentando por lo que solo te puedo comentar que si se puede usar `groupby` con columnas booleanas, por ejemplo podemos obtener los dataframes a partir del primer ejemplo que doy con algo como  `gb = df.groupby("PROB")`; `verdaderos = gb.get_group(True)`; `falsos = gb.get_group(False)`. No obstante es mucho más simple y eficiente en este caso usar un filtro booleano. Un saludo.