# Problema con funcion pandas.DataFrame.cumsum

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Tengo el siguiente dataframe en python:

```
month = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4]
active = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
data1 = [1709.1,3869.7,4230.4,4656.9,48566.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,93738.2,189293.2,194412.6,206585.8]
df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'month' : month,
                    'active' : active,
                    'd1' : data1,
                    'calculate' : 0,
                });
```

y requiero calcular la columna 'calculate', de la siguiente manera:

```
    month  active        d1  calculate
0       1       1    1709.1     569.70
1       2       1    3869.7    1859.60
2       3       1    4230.4    3269.73
3       4       1    4656.9    4822.03
4       5       0   48566.0       0.00
5       6       0       0.0       0.00
6       7       0       0.0       0.00
7       8       0       0.0       0.00
8       9       0       0.0       0.00
9      10       0       0.0       0.00
10     11       0       0.0       0.00
11     12       0       0.0       0.00
12     13       0       0.0       0.00
13     14       0       0.0       0.00
14     15       0       0.0       0.00
15     16       0       0.0       0.00
16     17       0       0.0       0.00
17     18       0       0.0       0.00
18     19       0       0.0       0.00
19     20       0       0.0       0.00
20      1       1   93738.2   31246.07
21      2       1  189293.2   94343.80
22      3       1  194412.6  159148.00
23      4       1  206585.8  228009.93
```

lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera:

```
df['calculate'] = np.where(
                        df.month > 1,
                        np.where(
                                    df.active,
                                    (df.d1/3).cumsum(),
                                    0,
                        ),
                        (df['d1']/3)
                    )
```

pero el resultado no es el esperado:

```
    month  active        d1      calculate
0       1       1    1709.1     569.700000
1       2       1    3869.7    1859.600000
2       3       1    4230.4    3269.733333
3       4       1    4656.9    4822.033333
4       5       0   48566.0       0.000000
5       6       0       0.0       0.000000
6       7       0       0.0       0.000000
7       8       0       0.0       0.000000
8       9       0       0.0       0.000000
9      10       0       0.0       0.000000
10     11       0       0.0       0.000000
11     12       0       0.0       0.000000
12     13       0       0.0       0.000000
13     14       0       0.0       0.000000
14     15       0       0.0       0.000000
15     16       0       0.0       0.000000
16     17       0       0.0       0.000000
17     18       0       0.0       0.000000
18     19       0       0.0       0.000000
19     20       0       0.0       0.000000
20      1       1   93738.2   31246.066667
21      2       1  189293.2  115354.500000
22      3       1  194412.6  180158.700000
23      4       1  206585.8  249020.633333
```

no se si soy claro en mi solicitud, agradezco a quien me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no me equivoco pretendes calcular la suma acumulada por grupos, agrupando primero por `month` y luego dentro de cada grupo anterior agrupar de nuevo en función de los periodos de actividad (filas contiguas con valor 1 en `active`).

Una posibilidad es usar `groupby` para obtener los grupos y luego aplicar `pandas.Series.groupby.cumsum`. Para [detectar cada grupo nos podemos ayudar de `shift` y `cumsum`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/99059/15089).

```
import pandas as pd


month = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4]
active = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
data1 = [1709.1,3869.7,4230.4,4656.9,48566.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,93738.2,189293.2,194412.6,206585.8]
df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'month' : month,
                    'active' : active,
                    'd1' : data1,
                    'calculate' : 0,
                })




month_parts = (df["month"] < df["month"].shift()).cumsum()
mask = df["active"] == 1
active_parts = (mask != mask.shift(1)).cumsum()

aux = df.loc[mask, "d1"] / 3

df['calculate'] = aux.groupby([month_parts, active_parts]).cumsum()
df['calculate'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>     month  active        d1      calculate
> 0       1       1    1709.1     569.700000
> 1       2       1    3869.7    1859.600000
> 2       3       1    4230.4    3269.733333
> 3       4       1    4656.9    4822.033333
> 4       5       0   48566.0       0.000000
> 5       6       0       0.0       0.000000
> 6       7       0       0.0       0.000000
> 7       8       0       0.0       0.000000
> 8       9       0       0.0       0.000000
> 9      10       0       0.0       0.000000
> 10     11       0       0.0       0.000000
> 11     12       0       0.0       0.000000
> 12     13       0       0.0       0.000000
> 13     14       0       0.0       0.000000
> 14     15       0       0.0       0.000000
> 15     16       0       0.0       0.000000
> 16     17       0       0.0       0.000000
> 17     18       0       0.0       0.000000
> 18     19       0       0.0       0.000000
> 19     20       0       0.0       0.000000
> 20      1       1   93738.2   31246.066667
> 21      2       1  189293.2   94343.800000
> 22      3       1  194412.6  159148.000000
> 23      4       1  206585.8  228009.933333
> ```

El ejemplo no es muy bueno si efectivamente deseas esto ya que hay coincidencia entre el periodo de actividad con el inicio de un nuvo rango en `month`, un ejemplo que muestra mejor el funcionamiento del código:

```
month = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4]
active = [1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
data1 = [1709.1,3869.7,4230.4,4656.9,48566.0,0,4000.0,5231.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45215.2,2154.1,451.2,14523.21,93738.2,189293.2,194412.6,206585.8]
df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'month' : month,
                    'active' : active,
                    'd1' : data1,
                    'calculate' : 0,
                })


month_parts = (df["month"] < df["month"].shift()).cumsum()
mask = df["active"] == 1
active_parts = (mask != mask.shift(1)).cumsum()

aux = df.loc[mask, "d1"] / 3

df['calculate'] = aux.groupby([month_parts, active_parts]).cumsum()
df['calculate'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

---

> ```
> >>> df
>     month  active         d1      calculate
> 0       1       1    1709.10     569.700000  <-----
> 1       2       1    3869.70    1859.600000
> 2       3       1    4230.40    3269.733333
> 3       4       1    4656.90    4822.033333
> 4       5       0   48566.00       0.000000
> 5       6       0       0.00       0.000000
> 6       7       1    4000.00    1333.333333  <-----
> 7       8       1    5231.40    3077.133333
> 8       9       0       0.00       0.000000
> 9      10       0       0.00       0.000000
> 10     11       0       0.00       0.000000
> 11     12       0       0.00       0.000000
> 12     13       0       0.00       0.000000
> 13     14       0       0.00       0.000000
> 14     15       0       0.00       0.000000
> 15     16       0       0.00       0.000000
> 16     17       1   45215.20   15071.733333  <-----
> 17     18       1    2154.10   15789.766667
> 18     19       1     451.20   15940.166667
> 19     20       1   14523.21   20781.236667
> 20      1       1   93738.20   31246.066667  <-----
> 21      2       1  189293.20   94343.800000
> 22      3       1  194412.60  159148.000000
> 23      4       1  206585.80  228009.933333
> ```